# How to make text and buttons stick to the background?

Tags: html, css

I am currently having problems with a website. I am trying to make the text stay in the same place when the page is either viewed on larger screens or when zooming out (zoom out and see for yourselves). I have the same problem with the buttons on the right side. Can anyone tell me how I can solve this?

http://ronnym.tk/

Please help me with this. I have no clue what to do, I tried absolute positioning, individually positioning divs with margins, nothing works. I think the parent's parameters overwrites the child parameters or something. I honestly don't know what else to try. Wasted days already.

Here is my HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html">
 <head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   if(typeof Muse == "undefined") window.Muse = {}; window.Muse.assets = {"required":["jquery-1.8.3.min.js", "museutils.js", "jquery.musepolyfill.bgsize.js", "index.css"], "outOfDate":[]};
</script>
  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="generator" content="2014.0.1.264"/>
  <title>HOME</title>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site_global.css?475048684"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css?4024854745" id="pagesheet"/>
  <!-- Other scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.documentElement.className += ' js';
var __adobewebfontsappname__ = "muse";
</script>
  <!-- JS includes -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.write('\x3Cscript src="' + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//webfonts.creativecloud.com/cambo:n4:all.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
</script>
   </head>
 <body>

  <div class="clearfix" id="page"><!-- group -->
   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu203-4"><!-- column -->
    <img class="colelem" id="u203-4" alt="ABOUT ME" width="171" height="41" src="images/u203-4.png"/><!-- rasterized frame -->
    <div class="clearfix colelem" id="u205-24" data-ice-editable="html" data-ice-options="disableImageResize,none" data-muse-uid="U205"><!-- content -->
     <p id="u205-2">My name is Ronny Minkovsky, and I'm a graphics designer and artist, currently based somewhere behind a computer screen.</p>
     <p id="u205-3">&nbsp;</p>
     <p id="u205-5">About 6 years ago, I realized my passion for art, and began a self&#45;taught career... for now.</p>
     <p id="u205-6">&nbsp;</p>
     <p id="u205-8">Ever since my childhood days, I've always loved gaming, and developed a real passion for its graphics, a passion that eventually lead me into creating, and participating in the art production of several games, one of which will be released on steam shortly, by the name of CivCraft.</p>
     <p id="u205-9">&nbsp;</p>
     <p id="u205-11">I'm majorly inspired by the Cyberpunk genre, and by authors such as Philip K. Dick, H. P. Lovecraft, Edgar Allan Poe, and Baudrillard and have been gaming since the good old days of Divine Divinity, and Ultima.</p>
     <p id="u205-12">&nbsp;</p>
     <p id="u205-14">Even though I prefer gaming graphics, I also tend to be versatile, working on web design, and advertising as well.</p>
     <p id="u205-15">&nbsp;</p>
     <p id="u205-17">I know my way around a number of digital art programs, mainly Photoshop, Illustrator, and Sketchbook Pro.</p>
     <p id="u205-18">&nbsp;</p>
     <p id="u205-20">Take a moment to browse through my Projects section, where I uploaded a few works from different fields, or skim through the Artwork tab for random art I made.</p>
     <p id="u205-21">&nbsp;</p>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu400"><!-- column -->
    <a class="nonblock nontext museBGSize colelem" id="u400" href="mailto:portal-m@hotmail.com"><!-- simple frame --></a>
    <a class="nonblock nontext museBGSize colelem" id="u383" href="callto://portal230762"><!-- simple frame --></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="preload_images">
   <img class="preload" src="images/mail%20button1-o.png" alt=""/>
   <img class="preload" src="images/mail%20button1-m.png" alt=""/>
   <img class="preload" src="images/mail%20button1-n.png" alt=""/>
   <img class="preload" src="images/skype%20button-over.png" alt=""/>
   <img class="preload" src="images/skype%20button-mouse%20down.png" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <!-- JS includes -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   if (document.location.protocol != 'https:') document.write('\x3Cscript src="http://musecdn.businesscatalyst.com/scripts/4.0/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.jQuery || document.write('\x3Cscript src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');
</script>
  <script src="scripts/museutils.js?353204447" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.musepolyfill.bgsize.js?323834883" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Other scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { try {
(function(){var a={},b=function(a){if(a.match(/^rgb/))return a=a.replace(/\s+/g,"").match(/([\d\,]+)/gi)[0].split(","),(parseInt(a[0])<<16)+(parseInt(a[1])<<8)+parseInt(a[2]);if(a.match(/^\#/))return parseInt(a.substr(1),16);return 0};(function(){$('link[type="text/css"]').each(function(){var b=($(this).attr("href")||"").match(/\/?css\/([\w\-]+\.css)\?(\d+)/);b&&b[1]&&b[2]&&(a[b[1]]=b[2])})})();(function(){$("body").append('<div class="version" style="display:none; width:1px; height:1px;"></div>');
for(var c=$(".version"),d=0;d<Muse.assets.required.length;){var f=Muse.assets.required[d],g=f.match(/([\w\-\.]+)\.(\w+)$/),l=g&&g[1]?g[1]:null,g=g&&g[2]?g[2]:null;switch(g.toLowerCase()){case "css":l=l.replace(/\W/gi,"_").replace(/^([^a-z])/gi,"_$1");c.addClass(l);var g=b(c.css("color")),h=b(c.css("background-color"));g!=0||h!=0?(Muse.assets.required.splice(d,1),"undefined"!=typeof a[f]&&(g!=a[f]>>>24||h!=(a[f]&16777215))&&Muse.assets.outOfDate.push(f)):d++;c.removeClass(l);break;case "js":l.match(/^jquery-[\d\.]+/gi)&&
typeof $!="undefined"?Muse.assets.required.splice(d,1):d++;break;default:throw Error("Unsupported file type: "+g);}}c.remove();(Muse.assets.outOfDate.length||Muse.assets.required.length)&&alert("Some files on the server may be missing or incorrect. Clear browser cache and try again. If the problem persists please contact website author.")})()})();/* body */
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblemsPreInit();/* body */
Muse.Utils.prepHyperlinks(true);/* body */
Muse.Utils.showWidgetsWhenReady();/* body */
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblems();/* body */
} catch(e) { if (e && 'function' == typeof e.notify) e.notify(); else Muse.Assert.fail('Error calling selector function:' + e); }});
</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS code

```css
.version.index /* version checker */
{
 color: #0000EF;
 background-color: #E668D9;
}

.html
{
 background-color: #000000;
}

#page
{
 z-index: 1;
 max-width:100%;
 height: auto;
 border-style: none;
 border-color: transparent;
 padding-bottom: 212px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background: transparent url("../images/home%20back%20(smaller).jpg") no-repeat center center;
}

#pu203-4
{
 width: 0.01px;
 margin-right: -10000px;
 margin-top: 478px;
 margin-left: 138px;
        position: relative;
}

#u203-4
{
 z-index: 2;
 display: block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-left: 138px;
 position: relative;
}

#u205-24
{
 z-index: 6;
 min-width: 465px;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 29px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
 position: relative;
        
}

#u205-2,#u205-3,#u205-5,#u205-6,#u205-8,#u205-9,#u205-11,#u205-12,#u205-14,#u205-15,#u205-17,#u205-18,#u205-20,#u205-21
{
 width:100%;
        font-size: 11px;
 line-height: 13px;
 color: #86A4B2;
 font-family: cambo, serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

#pu400
{
 width: 0.01px;
 margin-right: -10000px;
 margin-top: 570px;
 margin-left: 892px;
}

#u400
{
 z-index: 31;
 width: 354px;
 height: 120px;
 position: relative;
 background: transparent url("../images/mail%20button1-a.png") no-repeat left top;
 background-size: contain;
}

#u400:hover
{
 margin: 0px;
 background: transparent url("../images/mail%20button1-o.png") no-repeat left top;
 background-size: contain;
}

#u400:active
{
 margin: 0px;
 background: transparent url("../images/mail%20button1-m.png") no-repeat left top;
 background-size: contain;
}

#u400.MuseLinkActive
{
 margin: 0px;
 background: transparent url("../images/mail%20button1-n.png") no-repeat left top;
 background-size: contain;
}

#u383
{
 z-index: 30;
 width: 354px;
 height: 120px;
 top: -8px;
 margin-bottom: -8px;
 position: relative;
 background: transparent url("../images/skype%20button-active%20(normal).png") no-repeat left top;
 background-size: contain;
}

#u383:hover
{
 margin: 0px 0px -8px;
 background: transparent url("../images/skype%20button-over.png") no-repeat left top;
 background-size: contain;
}

#u383:active
{
 margin: 0px 0px -8px;
 background: transparent url("../images/skype%20button-mouse%20down.png") no-repeat left top;
 background-size: contain;
}

body
{
 position: relative;
 min-width: 1280px;
        max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, on the phone right now and hard to type a full answer, but to keep the text in the same place you can use fixed position: fixed, and to keep the zoom the same you can use an inverse zoom. In other words: 1/zoomlevel.

Comment: Won't "fixed" keep the text in a fixed position on the screen regardless of the scroll/zoom? I am also interested to view the site on bigger screens.  Won't it also scale the background making pixels visible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a wrapper for your page as following:

```
<div class="wrap"> all your page content </div>
```

using this CSS:

```
.wrap {width=800px; margin: 0px auto;}
```

This will automatically horizontally center the DIV wrapper, as well as making sure that all the content within always stays at the same place, relative to the wrapper.
You can still expand the page vertically by adding more content or adding a height value.

You might want to change the Width if 800px is too much or too little, but make sure it's a constant (px) value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that, putting all content under /body in it, including the scripts, then without the scripts, I tried putting the CSS code in both the .css files (index.css and site_global.css - since both are declared at the beginning of the .html file) and nothing changes.... I'm at my wits' end and it's like someone doesn't want me to get this done.

I think, since nothing happened, that for some reason, it doesn't read new code. Overwritten by the #body or #page CSS? I have no clue. 

I also tried using a container before the wrap idea. Same result.

Comment: If you are using firefox, try using firebug, you can browse through the HTML and CSS applied to it, as well as simply selecting a part of the page, and generally it'll fetch you the right item in the code browser. If you aren't using firefox, then there are usually many similar tools, some even already included with the browser itself; an HTML viewer (and live editor) are must haves for an HTML programmer.

Comment: Not having a problem discerning what is what, thank you.